# Read date value from import Excel in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I've problem with read date value from import value (Excel) to mysql database. i've code as below :

```
$dataexcel[$i-3]['date_edit'] = date('m/d/Y', strtotime(trim($data['cells'][$i][25])));
```

i tried use `strtotime`to define value from excel, but i've problem to save it into database, if my value in excel with excel date format is `1/1/2018` (it read as 1 Jan 2018, English time format), after i used my code above, it saved become `1970-01-01` it means 1 Jan 1970.

in another example, 
i tried another input with date `2/1/2018`, it saved into database as `2018-02-02`.

from my samples above, in first there missmatch problem with year, then and in the 2nd sample missmatch problem come from date,

so how to declare date to solve my problem, if i want to save date format with simple way?
if there any advice , please, thanks...

Comment: What is the actual value in `$data['cells'][$i][25]`.... not the value that you see when you open the file in MS Excel, the actual value read from the file by your code

Comment: And what library are you using to read this data? Are you actually using the PHPExcel library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment answer, you can modification some code like below :

```
$date = str_replace("/", ".", $data['cells'][$i][25]);
$dates = date("Y-m-j", strtotime($date));
$dataexcel[$i-3]['date_edit']  = $dates;
```

$date still pick up from value without used `strotime`, so date format didn't read correctly...

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the excel date to mysql date like below I did.

```
//Your input date
$input_date = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,$i)->getValue();

$excel_date = $input_date;  //here is that excel value 41621 or 41631

//Convert excel date to mysql db date
      $unix_date = ($excel_date - 25569) * 86400;
      $excel_date = 25569 + ($unix_date / 86400);
      $unix_date = ($excel_date - 25569) * 86400;
      //echo gmdate("Y-m-d", $unix_date);

//Insert below to sql
$added_date = gmdate("Y-m-d", $unix_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

keep it simple. use a defined dateformat when reading the file (the dateformat can be provided as a parameter in case it needs to be adjustable). then, read the date in the following way instead of just using strtotime (taken from php.net's example):

`$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');`

relevant example to your code, using the previous $date var:

`$dataexcel[$i-3]['date_edit'] = $date->format("y-M-Y");`

more info - http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: it saved become `0000-00-00`

Comment: made the example more clear, please check it again and use the link provided if you need more customizations (like different formats)

Answer (score 0):

A simple function will do this thing

```
    $date = str_replace("/", ".", $data['cells'][$i][25]);// replace the / with .
    $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
    $dataexcel[$i-3]['date_edit']  = $date;
```

And in the database the default date format is YYYY-MM-DD , so it save correctly to the db

Comment: what is the value associated with $data['cells'][$i][25]?

Comment: you can see in my capture below, i remark with red line, it's from column Month Target
[link]http://prntscr.com/i82qdc

Comment: see the link https://3v4l.org/i1Bvo , this is working here, maybe in the last line $dataexcel[$i-3]['date_edit']  = $date; it is not assigning properly